# Making a new column based on a function which gives ValueError

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with two columns: one containing a zero and one value and the other column contains a numeric value.

```
  ZeroOne   Value
    0       10
    1       20
    0       15
```

The goal is to make a new column where, if the ZeroOne column contains a '0', the value of the value column is put. If the ZeroOne value is 1, the new column should be 0. So, in my example, this should be the result:

```
  ZeroOne   Value   Result
   0        10          10
   1        20           0
   0        15          15
```

I have tried to make a function:

```
def function(a,b):
    if a == 1:
        return b
    else:
        return 0
```

And then made the variables a and b

```
    a = df['ZeroOne']
    b = df['Value']
```

and after this, I added a new column with this function

```
   df['result'] = function(a,b)
```

It keeps giving me the valueerror:

```
   The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I achieve my result and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do if `a.any()`: instead of `if a == 1:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case you can use `np.where` from the numpy library:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['ZeroOne'] == 0, df['Value'], 0)
```

It is similiar to Adams Soluation, but you could also add other conditions to it, the first space in the function gives you the condition, then what happens if it is True and then what happens if it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try using `where`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"ZeroOne": [0, 1, 0], "Value": [10, 20, 15]})

df['Result'] = (df['Value'].where(cond=df['ZeroOne'] == 0, other=0))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value  ZeroOne  Result
0     10        0      10
1     20        1       0
2     15        0      15
```